# Why can't I find the value of $x$ using logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, logarithms, exponential-function

This is concerning a question in stack exchange : [Sum of real values of $x$ satisfying the equation $(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793871/sum-of-real-values-of-x-satisfying-the-equation-x2-5x5x24x-60-1). I was actually wondering why the correct result is not obtained when applying $\log$ on both sides,like how the second answer does.Why is this so? Is it possible to get this answer using logarithms?

Comment: You can also [link to that specific answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you have mentioned use indeed logarithm, that is for $A>0$

$$A^B=1 \iff \log A^B=\log 1 \iff B\cdot \log A=0 \iff B=0 \quad \lor \quad \log A=0$$

Note that usually $A^B$ is (well-)defined only for $A>0$ but we could also extend the solutions to the case

- $A=-1$
- $B=2k$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

and include also the case $x=2$ among the solutions since $$(-1)^{-52}=\frac1{(-1)^{52}}=1$$

To summarize in order to address your question:

- $A^B=1$ can be solved by logarithm only for the case $A>0$
- $A^B=1$ has also one "special" solution for $A\le 0$ which cannot be find by logarithm but directly by the given conditions

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right! We can use logarithm here:
$$(x^2+4x-60)\ln(x^2-5x+5)=0,$$ which gives
$$x^2-5x+5=1$$ or
$$x^2+4x-60=0.$$
By the way, I think the accepted answer on your link is total wrong because if we wrote $$(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}$$ then $x^2-5x+5>0$ by definition.

Comment: Can you please explain '$x^2-5x+5 > 0$ by definition'?

Comment: @Michael Maybe we could also extend the solution to the case A=-1 B=2k.What your thought about that?

Comment: @Toby Mak If we want to work with expressions like $\left(f(x)\right)^{g(x)}$ then we need $f(x)>0.$

Comment: @gimusi Try to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow2}(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}.$ I think now you'll understand me.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I had in mind a solution like that one for x=2 we obtain $(-1)^{-52}=\frac1{(-1)^{52}}=1$.

Comment: @gimusi Yes $(-1)^{-52}=1$, but my limit does not exist. If we want to work with this expression we need $x^2-5x+5>0$. It's a definition only, but it's a very comfortable definition.

Comment: I agree with you and when we deal with calculus issues it is often a necessary limitation but here for an algebraic problem plugging x=2 we obtain the equality therefore I think that assuming that as a solution shouldn’t be considered a mistake.

Comment: @gimusi I think this situation must be impossible in math. What is it: sometimes we think that the domain of $(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}$ it's $\{x|x^2-5x+5>0\}$ and sometimes we don't think so?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I mean that in the algebraic perspective we can see at $$(x^2-5x+5)^{x^2+4x-60}=1$$ as an identity between expression without any needing of the concept of function and we can find others solution for $x\in \mathbb{N}$. I don't claim that it is a correct or official option but of course it is a reasonable option.

Comment: @gimusi I don't agree with you! We have a function here. We can not ignore this. Say me please. What is a value of the expression $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ for $x=0$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That's a completely different case Michaeland I like do not agree with you sometimes! :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg To explain better my point, the question is not find $a$ such that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}=1$ but find x such that  $f(x)^{g(x)}=1$ and for the latter $x=2$ works. (Note that also the tag is precalculus)

Comment: @gimusi It does not change something. Is algebra-precalculus not math?  If we want to get something in math we need to use a language, which helps to make it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Indeed it is math and $(-1)^{-52}=1$ [wolfy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%5E(-52)). Just to clarify, I'm not claiming that you are wrong, I'm claiming that other ways cannot be considered absolutely wrong giving the correct context. I think we can agree about that and (+1) for the nice discussion :)

Comment: @gimusi Yes, of course! It's a definition only, but I think  it's a very comfortable definition. I wrote in my post that it's my opinion only.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg We agree on that, it is of course a useful and covenient convention/definition in calculus context but in other context it could limit the number of solutions we can find and usually we don't like that! That's nice, I'll take a look to your editing!

Comment: when you take logarithm, is not the rule: $(x^2+4x-60)\ln|x^2-5x+5|=0$, which may be the cause of problem, no?

Comment: @farruhota I think it wold be another problem.